# Wicket without web.xml ; pure java configuration

Tags: java, wicket, config, web.xml

I need a way to configure Wicket without using the web.xml .

I have tried several blog posts but still got problems with it.

For example:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket+without+web.xml+%28embedded+Jetty%29

and

http://dev-loki.blogspot.de/2008/05/embedded-jetty-wicketfilter-webxml.html

Can't find a working solution.

I created a simple project with just one HomePage, followed the steps in the links mentioned above and couldn't get any success.

I tried jetty and got a HTTP ERROR 404. I can show you the code that should act like a web.xml.  It's a spring based solution.

```
public class WicketApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(SpringConfig.class);

    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

    WicketFilter filter = new WicketFilter(new WicketApplication());
    filter.setFilterPath("");

    servletContext.addFilter("wicketFilter", filter).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    servletContext.addServlet("/*", DefaultServlet.class);

}
```

}

This should do the trick, but didn't get recognized by the server. It looks simple and just like the steps in a normal web.xml but doesn't work.

There is only one mounting to a HomePage:

```
mountPage("/testing", HomePage.class);
```

Trying to access:

```
https://localhost:8443/testing
```

results in an:

```
HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /testing. Reason:  Not Found
```

Anyone can help?

Maybe someone has a minimalistic working project without the ugly web.xml ? or just some advices.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please show us [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) besides asking us?

Comment: Didn't see my links? I tried these approaches. (Created a new project with just one HomePage, followed the instructions, can't view the page)

Comment: What are the problem you have when you try the solutions from the links? And, out of curiosity: why do you want to get rid of the web.xml?

Comment: Please show us **exactly** what **you** have tried. Also tell us what does not work for you. Also please note that a question with links is discouraged on this site (the reasons are explained in detail [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)).

Comment: I can't access any Pages. I get a 404. I want to get rid of the web.xml because it's a requirement of an project i'm actually working on. I try to integrate Wicket into this project and get rid of ugly jsp's.

Comment: At first, I thought this question was really obvious and should be closed, but then I googled this, trying terms someone who don't actually know the answer would use, like 'filter without web.xml', and I couldn't find good, direct answers for them. Sure, if I search for 'servlet filter annotations', I get tons of results, but I would have to know that 'annotations' is the solution in the first place, and just look for the details. @DaUser, try these terms, on how to configure servlet filters with annotations, and you'll find your answer.

Comment: @tetsu Thats not the real point. I stepped a little bit further in processing this but still no real function. But my WicketApplicationInitializer gets noticed by the jetti now. I added some code to tell the jetty : "Pick up the WebApplicationInitializer classes". Jetty cant do it out-of-the-box. But as i said, still 404 but Wicket tells me it runs in development mode... hope to find the solution soon.

Comment: ok. a question though: your application will run on an embedded jetty when in production, or do you plan to deploy it into other containers? This method you're using will only work in this specific case (0% portable)

Comment: yes it will run on a jetty

Comment: @DaUser, why is it a requirement not to use a configuration file? I understand you want to get rid of ugly jsps, that's what Wicket is for, but what does this have to do with a web.xml that is standard for any Web Application? Having all that information hardcoded doesn't seem like a good idea. Don't forget that you only have to map your Wicket Application and then you're up and running. Nevertheless, I posted some option I found as an answer, you should be able to do what you need with that, but as others have stated, t might be fine for some testing environment...

Comment: @Martin, because this project uses some other servlets and their configuration without a web.xml . I don't want to add a web.xml only because of the Wicket integration ; there are ways without it. I found some kind of a way for Wicket, but not what i needed. My new goal is to use the WebApplicationInitializer of Spring. But there i face some other problems which i try to solve right now... I'll post you a solution for "wicket + jetty (without Spring)". But as i said, now i'm on the way for the Spring solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code starts a jetty with support for wicket without the web.xml.

```
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Object that holds, and configures the WicketServlet.
        ServletHolder servletHolder =
                new ServletHolder(new WicketServlet());
        servletHolder.setInitParameter(
                "applicationClassName",
                "com.javaeenotes.ExampleWicketApplication");
        servletHolder.setInitParameter(
                WicketFilter.FILTER_MAPPING_PARAM, "/*");
        servletHolder.setInitOrder(1);

        // Web context configuration.
        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");
        context.setResourceBase("."); // Web root directory.

        // The HTTP-server on port 8080.
        Server server = new Server();
        SocketConnector connector = new SocketConnector();
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{connector});
        server.setHandler(context);

        try {
            // Start HTTP-server.
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a solution  by  http://javaeenotes.blogspot.de/2011/12/running-wicket-on-jetty.html

As i said before, this does not fit for me right now, but fits the topic: it's a jetty which can start wicket applications and don't need a web.xml configuration.

So, i mark this answer as accepted and maybe start another question for the Spring-way of wicket processing... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some code that starts jetty without a web.xml this way:

```
    import org.mortbay.jetty.Connector;
    import org.mortbay.jetty.Server;
    import org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector;
    import org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

    Server server = new Server();
    SelectChannelConnector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector.setPort(8000); //or any other port you need
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[]
    { connector });

    WebAppContext web = new WebAppContext();
    web.setContextPath("/"); //assuming you want / as a context like your sample
    web.setWar("src/webapp"); //check that it matches your webapp directory.
    server.addHandler(web);
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

This way, you can add as many wars as you need to your context, assuming you use Jetty. You can add more stuff to the WebAppContext object (web) to control your filters and other mappings.

Comment: That is a way to start, yes! I posted another Answer which is ready to use for Wicket.